# Why doesn't this code loop through all properties of an object?

Tags: javascript

Here is a little code snippet:

```
cards = [ 4, 10, 3, 12, 10, 13, 12  ];
suits = [ 1, 64, 8, 8, 1, 1, 32 ];

var o = {}, keyCount = 0, j;

for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    e = cards[i] + suits[i];
    o[e] = 1
}

for (j in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
        keyCount++;
    }
}
```

After some debugging I found out that when I iterate through all the properties in the 'o' object (the second loop) the loop only executes 6 times instead of 7.

This is despite adding 7 properties to the 'o' object in the first loop.

Why is this? I have added 7 properties in the first loop so why does the second loop only execute 6 times?

Comment: Two of the values in `cards` are `12`. There can be only one property named `12` in `o`.

Comment: Actually that's wrong (close though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is not because the number 12 is in the cards array twice like Pointy said in the comments. He said that 2 properties cannot have the same value which helped me understand. I am saying that `e = cards[i] + suits[i];` It just so happens to be that sometimes these 2 values added together sometimes sum to the same answer. eg in this example 3 + 8 = 11 and 10 + 1 also = 11

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object cannot have duplicate key & above snippet is violating that, this is because 3+8 & 10+1 both equals to 11. It such scenerios it will take up the most recent value.So key need to be unique. Therefore change the integer to produce a different sum value.

```
cards = [ 4, 10, 3, 12, 11, 13, 12 ];
suits = [ 1, 64, 8, 8, 1, 1, 32 ];
```

[WORKING COPY](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/t1eokqa1/5/)

Comment: I imagine the point would be to make the code work with the input and not the other way around :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as most people have noticed, you have duplicates in your object. If you want to work with your current input data, try concatenating the numbers as strings instead of adding them - this will give you a larger set of possible values. Something like

```
e = cards[i]+":"+suits[i];
```

So you'll have keys of the form "4:1", "10:64" in your object. This is nice because you can also split them up to get the initial values again if you need them later.

Comment: 3:8 and 10:1 are different keys , so it make the same sense of having unique key